How to link a style sheet in php if the files are not in the same folder?
I have a php project structured like so :
├───public
│       index.php
├───styles
│       style.css
├───vendor
└───views
    ├───category
    │       show.php
    ├───layout
    │       footer.php
    │       header.php
    │       style.css
    └───post
            index.php

I use the public folder as my root folder and I run the php server with php -S localhost:3006 -t public.
What I am trying to do is to import the styles/style.css file into views/layout/header.php and require views/layout/header.php in all my pages, for instance in views/post/index.php I do :
<?php require VIEW_PATH . '/layout/header.php'; ?>

<h1>Blog</h1>

<?php require VIEW_PATH . '/layout/footer.php'; ?>

Here VIEW_PATH is a constant that refers to the path to the views folder.
I use AltoRouter to manage routes and I define the routes in public/index.php like so :
<?php
$router= new AltoRouter();
define('VIEW_PATH', dirname(__DIR__) . '/views');

$router->map('GET', '/blog', function(){
    require VIEW_PATH .'/post/index.php';
});
$router->map('GET', '/blog/category', function(){
    require VIEW_PATH . '/category/show.php';
});

$match= $router->match();
$match['target']();

I've tried doing this in /views/layout/header.php :
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../../styles/style.css">

But it didn't work so I tried using href="<?= __DIR__ . '/../../styles/style.css' ?>" which also didn't work.
Then I went to this post and tried all the answers but I am really confused about the folder I should use for referencing the relative paths : the layout folder where the header is or the post folder where I require the header or the public folder where I set the routes so none of the answer but one worked for me.
The answer suggested to include the css file directly like so :
<style>
<?php include 'CSS/main.css'; ?>
</style>

So in views/layout/header.php, I did :
<style type="text/css">
<?php require __DIR__ . '/../../styles/style.css'?>
</style>

and it worked.
This is the only way I could make it work but the problem with that is that it renders the whole content of the css file in the rendered HTML which would be the equivalent of putting all the css lines directly in the php file so my question is how can I link that css file using the <link> tag? Is it possible?
Thanks in advance.

The root folder for you web is the "public" folder and you can not navigate to any parent folder  of public  "/" which is you public folder and ../../../../../../ translates to "/".  Move the style.css to punlic folder of create a link to style in public folder and use the link to address the the style. If you are using any framework like Laravel. there is some function that works for you. like "asset('style.css')".

Thank you for the comment, I didn't think of that.

As explained in Mehrwarz's comment, you need to move your CSS assets in your public directory, your web server's root directory, in order to be able to serve them directly to the web browser with <link> HTML tags.
So your directory structure should look like:
├───public
│   │   index.php
│   └───styles
│           layout.css
│           style.css
├───vendor
└───views
    ├───category
    │       show.php
    ├───layout
    │       footer.php
    │       header.php
    └───post
            index.php

In this suggestion, I moved and/or renamed:

your styles/style.css to public/styles/style.css;
your views/layout/style.css to public/styles/layout.css.

They are now both serveable with <link> HTML tags.
The public/styles/style.css file path corresponds to the /styles/style.css URL.
The leading / makes the URL relative to your web server's root directory.
Your views/layout/header.php file may then simply use:
<link href="/styles/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />

And wherever you included your previous views/layout/style.css, you may use:
<link href="/styles/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" />

You will be also able to include them directly in other CSS assets.
For examples, you may include public/styles/layout.css in public/styles/style.css with:

a path relative to the public web server's root directory with the leading /:

@import "/styles/layout.css";


a path relative to the current file path, with or not a leading ./:

@import "./layout.css";

@import "layout.css";


Thank you. I just didn't think about putting my styles in the public folder.
